# How to set root permissions for one directory and delete another?

Tags: command-line, terminal

```
hieupa@cpt00108094a:/media$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root   4096 Th04  4 13:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x  24 root   root   4096 Th04  4 09:29 ../
drwxrwxrwx+  3 hieupa hieupa 4096 Th04  4 13:47 hieupa/
drwxr-x---+  2 root   root   4096 Th04  4 13:45 hieupalocal/
```

I have just created an user hieupa, but it not have permission root like that.
So How can I change hieupa hieupa to root root and then delete user hieupalocal
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Look at `man chown`. Do you mean delete user `hieupalocal`, or just directory `hieupalocal`?

Comment: Do you have root access? Did you try with `sudo…`?

Comment: I have just check and hieupalocal is a directory, so how can I delete it and change hieupa hieupa to root root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the directory permissions changed:

```
sudo chown heiupa:heiupa hieupa
```

If you want it to be recursive, affecting all the files within, run this instead:

```
sudo chown -R heiupa:heiupa hieupa
```

To delete the entire directory `hieupalocal` including the contents.

```
sudo rm -r hieupalocal
```

If you are prompted on whether you should "descend into write-protected directory", then just press "y" for yes. Alternatively, to skip the prompts, you can "force" the `rm` with:

```
sudo rm -rf hieupalocal
```

Comment: I changed to root, 
but can not delete directory
hieupa@cpt00108094a:/media$ rm -r hieupalocal/
rm: descend into write-protected directory 'hieupalocal/'?

Comment: I've edited it with more information anyway.